# https://ospry.io image hosting with api site is down

Tags: image, api, file-upload, image-uploading

I've been using ospry.io as a third side image hosting for my website,
Suddenly when entering the site I see the error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED https://code.ospry.io/v1/ospry.js

and also when trying to reach https://ospry.io I see the site is down.

has any of you encounter the same problem?
is there a way to get the images uploaded so far to that service?

Comment: Yep same here. No idea why though

Comment: they came back alive, not going to use them though.
i want something i could count on.